# Determining which file in a folder is the latest by "modified date"?

Tags: delphi

I need to scan a specific folder for the latest file (basically check the modified date to see which is the newest), But keep in mind that the files have random names. Here's what I got so far:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

ftp.Host := 'domain';
ftp.Username := 'username';
ftp.password := 'password';
ftp.Connect;
ftp.Put('random-filename.ext'); //This is where it should grab only the latest file  
ftp.Quit;
ftp.Disconnect;

end;
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: With FTP you need to use a LIST command, and to search the latest file in the list. Be careful because the LIST result format is not as standard and depends on the FTP server.

Comment: @philnext He trys to PUT something to ftp, not get

Comment: @Grrbrr404 !!! You are right. Wrong anwswer from me.

Comment: @John Rosenberg, your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to scan a specific **local** folder, find the most recent file and then upload it to FTP server, or you want to scan a specific **remote** folder on that FTP server?

Comment: @LightBulb yep, find latest local file and then upload to ftp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that OP wants to scan specific local folder and find the most recent modified file, here's a very simple function to do just that:

```
function GetLastModifiedFileName(AFolder: String; APattern: String = '*.*'): String;
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
  aTime: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  aTime := 0;
  if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(AFolder) + APattern, faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if sr.Time > aTime then
      begin
        aTime := sr.Time;
        Result := sr.Name;
      end;
    until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
    FindClose(sr);
  end;
end;
```

`AFolder` should be an absolute or relative path to a folder you want to scan, `APattern` is optional and should contain a standard DOS pattern that specifies which files should be checked. If nothing is specified for 2nd parameter, *.* (all files) is assumed. Result will be the file name that has the most recent modified date.

Comment: This function does work. However, I need to specify an extension, otherwise it returns a single dot as a result. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Specify extension with the 2nd parameter, like '\*.ext'. That will tell this function to scan only files with .ext extension.

Comment: you r genius mr bulb

Answer (score 2):

Because i think you are trying to put the latest file from your local machine to an ftp server, you can use the shell Api function: ShGetFileInfo

Get all files from your source folder first and then get the FileInfo for every file - Keep the filename with the latest modified date in a temp. var.

See this site for example: http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesDelphi06&Lang=EN

Comment: What does that have to do with loading up files on a FTP server? The "get file info, then custom sort" approach works generally.

Comment: @Smasher i was just referring to his code he posted in his question - he trys to upload the latest file to a ftp server - Of course my solution does always work

Comment: Okay, i just found your reasoning irritating: "**because** you want to upload to FTP, you can use `ShGetFileInfo`" ...