# Determining which folder in a directory is the latest by “modified date”?

Tags: delphi

How to determine which folder in a windows directory is the latest by 'modified date' ?
[Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292424/determining-which-file-in-a-folder-is-the-latest-by-modified-date), but for folder not file.

I need to create a function like `GetLastModifiedFolderName('D:\LogFolder\'):string;`

After some suggestion below (from MBo) then reading some [findfirst](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FindFirst) reference. I modified the answered link become like this one :

```
function TForm1.GetLastModifiedFolderName(AFolder: String): string;
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
  aTime: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  aTime := 0;

  if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(AFolder)+'*',faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
  begin
    // directory found
    repeat
      if (sr.Attr and faDirectory)=faDirectory then
      begin
        // directory only
        if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.name<>'..') then
        begin
          // exclude '.' and '..' directory
          if sr.Time > aTime then
          begin
            aTime := sr.Time;
            Result := sr.Name;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
   FindClose(sr);
 end else
  begin
    // not found
    Result:='-1';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: No article about it so far, after googling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use slightly modified function from linked answer. Because you need folders only, just check that filesystem object (found by FindXX functions) is a directory:

```
if (sr.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory ...
```

P.S. Note that fresh Delphi versions include System.IOUtils unit with variety of useful methods.